# How to create kotlin android sdk with jitpac?

Tags: android, kotlin, obfuscation, jitpack

Jitpac compiles my android sdk to Java from Kotlin. How to save sdk classes in Kotlin?

my jitpac.yml

```
jdk:
  - openjdk11
before_install:
  - ./scripts/prepareJitpackEnvironment.sh
```

It happens only with minifyEnabled true

Answer (score 0):

Minification isn't meant to be done on a library level, it's the app's responsibility. So setting `minifyEnabled` to `false` is the solution.

When an app has `minifyEnabled true`, and it includes your library, your library's code will also be obfuscated. See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code):

> Code shrinking (or tree-shaking): detects and safely removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes from your app and **its library dependencies**.

> Resource shrinking: removes unused resources from your packaged app, including unused resources in **your app’s library dependencies**.

(emphasis added)